# getRealPath("/")- How does the result of this method differ in Tomcat and WebSphere

Tags: websphere

Using the method

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

returns a  **"\"** in the end of the path in Tomcat (eg. C:\testfolder\myapp) whereas in Websphere it doesn't (eg. C:\testfolder\myapp) . 
What is the reason for this ? What is the relevance of ("/") in getRealPath("/") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Q-1: What is the relevance of ("/") in getRealPath("/")
```

/ refers to your root web context path. And the function returns the physical path of your web directory where your war/web app is installed.

```
Q-2 Why tomcat appends \ in the end and websphere does not.
```

Different Servers do vary in their results like you have mentioned because the API implementations vary from server to server when any part is vaguely defined by Java EE.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on your response in order to make an application work in different servers do we need to append extra slash at the end?

Comment: Nop, you don't need to append extra slash in the end.

Comment: for eg if i need to access a particular file, C:\testfolder\myapp\myfolder\myfile.txt where C:\testfolder\myapp is my root. When I use getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), it returns C:\testfolder\myapp\ in Tomcat and C:\testfolder\myapp in Websphere. How do I handle this to access myfile.txt?

Comment: if it is text file then just put it in your `classpath(WEB-INF/classes)` and use `InputStream text = 
   YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myfile.txt");`

Comment: what are you trying to do with this ? I don't get it.

Comment: It may not be a txt file always. It can be any file...I am storing the path to a variable .eg mypath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/"). Later on I will use this variable to access certain files and folders.eg.mypath+"somefolder"+fieldseperator+"somefile". So accessing the files and folders depends on mypath value. If there is no slash it will be like C:\testfolder\myappsomefolder\somefile instead of C:\testfolder\myapp\soomefolder\somefile.. So I need to get the paths right in websphere and tomcat.

Comment: You can load any file with `getResourceAsSream()` function, not just text file. You just put all your resources in `classpath` as I mentioned. No need to store path in variable.

Comment: I am not sure how does this solve the problem. I am using this function in jsp. and all I need is to find the path to my context root with or without slash at the end, what it matters is, it should work in the same way for both tomcat and websphere. I may access files or folders after finding the path which is not important now. I am not looking for a particular file always.i hope you understand my scenario. Thanks

Comment: Alright, you want path to your file, then use `URL url = getClass().getResource("/webappcontext/path to file")`. This will give you web URL and then you can use it anywhere including client side scripting. No need to worry about extra slashes.